# How to save loop id into qrcode?

Tags: javascript, loops, qr-code

I am trying to generate multiple different QR codes using while loop. Is it possible to the store loop id into the QR code?

I am using qrcode.js to generate th QR code. The image below is the result I got after running this code: the problem is, all QR codes will store the last loop id, which is 5, into the QR code.

[image: Image showing the hover text is "5"]

```js
let i = 1;
while (i <= 5) {
  var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), {
    width: 70,
    height: 70,
    colorDark: "#000000",
    colorLight: "#ffffff",
    correctLevel: QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
  });

  function makeCode() {
    var elText = document.getElementById("text");
    qrcode.makeCode(i);
  }

  makeCode();
  i++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/davidshimjs-qrcodejs@0.0.2/qrcode.min.js"></script>
<div id="qrcode"></div>
```

Comment: Hy Yumi, I am no java script pro but upon short googling I found out that other people had similar problems with the qr code object storing the last value. `$('#qrcode').html('');`  <- this line from this question [maybe related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45115027/generate-random-qr-code-onclick-using-qrcode-js)  could help if you call it before generating a new qr code. Hope I could help :)